# Visualizing exponentials of roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $\omega$ be the primitive $n$th root of unity. Then define the coordinates of

$(\omega^k,0)$ and $(0,\omega^k)$

for $k=1,...,n$. What do these points look like in $\mathbb{C}$ in a geometric sense? I am struggling to visualize these coordinates.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^2$ is four-dimensional (over $\mathbb{R}$), so you're talking about a geometric sense for points in 4D-space.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: In almost all cases $\omega^k \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, so those coordinates do not describe points in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What you might want to know: The $n$'th roots of unity (the exponentials of the primitive just gives the others) are the vertices of a regular $n$-gon in the typical visualisation of $\mathbb{C}$.